# How to query for a set type cassandra column using python?

Tags: python, cassandra

My cassandra table has a column of type `legs set<frozen<leg>>`.

I am using following classes for fetching data from my cassandra database:

```
from cassandra.query import dict_factory
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
```

I have functions for creating connection to cassandra and running a query.

```
def runSelect(self,query):
    return self.session.execute(query)
```

When I pass a query for selecting the columns of type `text`, `int` or `timestamp`, it works fine but if I try to select a `set` type column, it throws an error:

> "cassandra.InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query]
>
> Message="Cannot execute this query as it might involve data filtering and thus may have unpredictable performance. If you want to execute this query despite the performance unpredictability, use ALLOW FILTERING"

Comment: show data model and query used... Cassandra can efficiently query partition key and clustering key...

Comment: That error happens when you try to query on clustering columns. Can you please share the data model, user-defined type and the query.